# Factoring polynomials: $p_2(t)=2t^4+t^2+2 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[t]$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields, factoring

I want to factor the following polynomials into irreducible polynomials:
$$p_1(t)=t^4+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[t]$$

$$p_2(t)=2t^4+t^2+2 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[t]$$

$\mathbb{Z}_3:$

$\begin{pmatrix}+_{\mathbb{Z}_3} & 0& 1 &2 \\0 &0 &1 &2 \\1 &1 &2 &0 \\2 &2 &0 &1\end{pmatrix}$

$\begin{pmatrix}\cdot_{\mathbb{Z}_3} & 0& 1 &2 \\0 &0 &0 &0 \\1 &0 &1 &2 \\2 &0 &2 &1\end{pmatrix}$

So if I'm not wrong both polynomials should have no roots so I think there is nothing to do here. But according to my professor there is something to be done about $p_2$ and I could use some help there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's possible for a polynomial to factor into non-linear terms.  Here, since you have degree $4$, it might be the product of two quadratics.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb{Z}_3[t]$, you have$$t^4+1=(t^2-1)^2+2t^2=(t^2-1)^2-t^2=(t^2-t-1)(t^2+t-1)$$and$$2t^4+t^2+2=-t^4+t^2-1=t^2-\bigl((t^2+1)^2-2t^2\bigr)=-(t^2+1)^2.$$

Comment: Thanks but for the first one what if I approach it like this: $p_1(t)=t^4+1=(t^2+1)^2-2t^2=(t^2+1)^2+t^2=t^4+2t^2+1+t^2=t^4+1$. Is this correct? So maybe this is why our professor said that $p_1(t)$ is already irreducible but is it really? I like your approach but I would never see the last equation easily...

Comment: @user567319 I don't understand your question. How can you ask whether it is irreducible? Have I nott expressed it as the product of two quadratic polynomials?

Comment: Why did you go with $t^4+1=(t^2-1)^2+2t^2$ instead of $t^4+1=(t^2+1)^2-2*t^2$? If I use the second one I dont get the same result as you (see my comment above)

Comment: @udoismyname I tried to see what I would get starting with $t^4+1=(t^2+1)^2-2t^2$. And I got nothing. Then I tried $t^4+1=(t^2-1)^2+2t^2$ and then I used that fact that, in $\mathbb{Z}_3[t]$, $2t^2=-t^2$.